# Галерея фотографий

Tags: javascript, jquery

Для вывода галереи использую следующий код: 
Разметка:

```
<div class="gallery">
<div>
    <div class="photos">
        <img src="images/img-1.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="images/img-2.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="images/img-3.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="images/img-4.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="prev">Назад</button>
        <button class="next">Вперед</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="previews">
    <img src="images/img-1.jpg" alt="" data-num="0">
    <img src="images/img-2.jpg" alt="" data-num="1">
    <img src="images/img-3.jpg" alt="" data-num="2">
    <img src="images/img-4.jpg" alt="" data-num="3">
</div>
```

Скрипт:

```
var prev = document.querySelector(".gallery button.prev");
var next = document.querySelector(".gallery button.next");
var images = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery .photos img");
var i = 0;

if (next) {
next.onclick = function () {
    images[i].style.opacity = "0";
    i++;
    if (i >= images.length) {
        i = 0;
    }
    images[i].style.opacity = "1";
}}


if (prev) {
prev.onclick = function () {
    images[i].style.opacity = "0";
    i--;
    if (i < 0) {
        i = images.length - 1;
    }
    images[i].style.opacity = "1";
}}


$(function() {
    $(".gallery .previews img").click(function() {
        i = $(this).attr("data-num");
        $(".gallery .photos img").css("opacity","0");
        images[i].style.opacity = "1";
    })
})
```

Все работало до тех пор, пока не появилась необходимость поставить более 1й галереи на страницу. Когда их больше чем одна в из-за переменных images, prev, next работа нарушается.
Как можно модернизировать скрипт для корректной работы с большим количеством галерей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function Gallery(target) {
  this.target = $(target);
  this.images = $('.photos img', this.target);
  this.index = 0;
}

Gallery.prototype.init = function() {
  var self = this;
  $('button.next', this.target).click(function() {
    self.images.eq(self.index).css('opacity',  0);
    self.index++;
    if (self.index >= self.images.length) {
      self.index = 0;
    }
    self.images.eq(self.index).css('opacity', 1);
  });
  $('button.prev', this.target).click(function() {
    self.images.eq(self.index).css('opacity',  0);
    self.index--;
    if (self.index < 0) {
      self.index = self.images.length - 1;
    }
    self.images.eq(self.index).css('opacity', 1);
  });
  $('.previews img', this.target).click(function() {
    self.index = $(this).attr('data-num');
    self.images.css('opacity', 0);
    self.images.eq(self.index).css('opacity', 1);
  });
};

$(function() {
  $('.gallery').each(function() {
    new Gallery(this).init();      
  });
});
```

```css
.gallery {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.photos {
  height: 120px;
}

.photos img {
  height: 120px;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 160px;
}

.photos img:first-child {
  opacity: 1;
}

.previews img {
  height: 30px;
  width: 40px;
}

.color1 { background-color: #f00; }
.color2 { background-color: #f80; }
.color3 { background-color: #ff0; }
.color4 { background-color: #0f0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="photos">
    <img src="images/img-1.jpg" alt="Photo 1" class="color1"/>
    <img src="images/img-2.jpg" alt="Photo 2" class="color2"/>
    <img src="images/img-3.jpg" alt="Photo 3" class="color3"/>
    <img src="images/img-4.jpg" alt="Photo 4" class="color4"/>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="prev">Назад</button>
    <button class="next">Вперед</button>
  </div>
  <div class="previews">
    <img src="images/img-1.jpg" alt="1" data-num="0" class="color1"/>
    <img src="images/img-2.jpg" alt="2" data-num="1" class="color2"/>
    <img src="images/img-3.jpg" alt="3" data-num="2" class="color3"/>
    <img src="images/img-4.jpg" alt="4" data-num="3" class="color4"/>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
  <div class="photos">
    <img src="images/img-1.jpg" alt="Photo 1" class="color1"/>
    <img src="images/img-2.jpg" alt="Photo 2" class="color2"/>
    <img src="images/img-3.jpg" alt="Photo 3" class="color3"/>
    <img src="images/img-4.jpg" alt="Photo 4" class="color4"/>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="prev">Назад</button>
    <button class="next">Вперед</button>
  </div>
  <div class="previews">
    <img src="images/img-1.jpg" alt="1" data-num="0" class="color1"/>
    <img src="images/img-2.jpg" alt="2" data-num="1" class="color2"/>
    <img src="images/img-3.jpg" alt="3" data-num="2" class="color3"/>
    <img src="images/img-4.jpg" alt="4" data-num="3" class="color4"/>
  </div>
</div>
```